# Collection view flow layout not using correct cell width

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, below:

```
class SnapCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        // Page width used for estimating and calculating paging.
        let pageWidth = self.itemSize.width + self.minimumLineSpacing

        // Make an estimation of the current page position.
        let approximatePage = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.x/pageWidth

        // Determine the current page based on velocity.
        let currentPage = (velocity.x < 0.0) ? floor(approximatePage) : ceil(approximatePage)

        // Create custom flickVelocity.
        let flickVelocity = velocity.x * 0.3

        // Check how many pages the user flicked, if <= 1 then flickedPages should return 0.
        let flickedPages = (abs(round(flickVelocity)) <= 1) ? 0 : round(flickVelocity)

        // Calculate newHorizontalOffset.
        let newHorizontalOffset = ((currentPage + flickedPages) * pageWidth) - self.collectionView!.contentInset.left

        return CGPoint(x: newHorizontalOffset, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
    }

}
```

However, `self.itemSize.width` is returning the value `50.0`, rather than the cell's actual width.

The collection view I have is a horizontal collection view with cells of dynamic width/height (specifically, they are 16:9 aspect ratios, so it depends on the screen size).

How can I use the correct `itemSize` width to reflect the real width of the cell?

Here is my `sizeForItemAt` function from the collection view class:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let imageWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let imageHeight = imageWidth / (16 / 9)

    return CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, although I'm not using a custom flow layout. I could change the height of the itemSize, but the width wouldn't change. I tried both programmatically and through the storyboard, but the width was always the same. I was trying to change it in viewDidLoad, though. When I changed the width in viewDidLayoutSubviews, finally the width got updated.